# Importing csv into QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, import

[image][image]Very basic question, just started to use QGIS. I've been trying to import my own csv file with lat/long into QGIS. No luck, thought it was my excel file that was not with the proper format.

I tried with the file 'us_states_locations-1.csv' provided with QGIS when you download it. No luck either, same result. Here is the print screen. [image]When I click ok, the system crash. Any idea of what I do wrong?

Comment: CSV is a plain text file. Let them show you with a texteditor.
Otherwise, you should provide the CSV here.

Comment: Try with the format being comma separated values instead of custom delimiters. Not sure if that is what is the error. But it could work.

Comment: Although you could select CSV instead of custom delimiter->Comma, you're settings seem correct to me. Can you show us the content of the minidump file that has been written ?

Comment: I got the files here but how do I import them? Feeling stupid right now...

Comment: @RoVo: Tried and had the same result as above... Thanks!

Comment: If each line from the csv file looks the same, you could just post the first 10-20 lines. I don't know how long the dump file is, but maybe you could post the "important" part of the file. Considering you know which part is important.

Comment: I just got a crash using a csv file that has worked in the past - maybe a bug? I've asked on the user list

Comment: Add a sample of my xlsx and csv. Can't provide .dmp. Computer provided by my office doesn't have any software to read it and I don't have admin rights...

Comment: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16600#change-79959

Comment: Looks like a bug, as using an older version and is working with csv, note you can use multiple versions of QGIS on the same PC. https://qgis.org/downloads/

Comment: @Mike, Thanks. Reinstalled the software from the beginning. Got one step forward, the Coordinate Reference System Selector popped-up. I selected WGS 84, clicked ok then crashed again, same error message as above.

Comment: Tried an older version and it worked. Thanks @Mapperz

Comment: If you are looking for a Quick&Dirty method to import your data:
In the text editor (Notepad): replace "," with ";" and save the file.
In QGIS: import with delimiter = semicolon.
Any luck?